# HTML structure is printed as it is in email code

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send email with a HTML structure but the HTML structure is printed as it is in the email. I have used following two lines in the email code:

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

But there is no improvement.

```
 $email_subject =  $cnm ." |abc.com";
            $email_message ="<HTML><BODY><TABLE>";
            $email_message .= "<TR><TD> Job Descrption :".$jb_des ."</TD></TR>\r\n\n";
            $email_message .="<TR><TD>Employer Name :".$frm_nm." </TD></TR>" ."\r\n\n";
            $email_message .="<TR><TD>Company Name :".$cnm." </TD></TR>" ."\r\n\n";
            $email_message .="<TR><TD>Message :".$msg." </TD></TR>" ."\r\n\n";
            $email_message .="<TR><TD>Title of Job Opening :".$job_ti." </TD></TR>" ."\r\n\n";
            $email_message .="</TABLE></BODY></HTML>";
            $headers = "From:<$frm_nm@".DOMAIN_WEBMAIL.">"."\r\n\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";  
            @mail($to_em,$email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to put a head in you're html email?

or maybe use another header.

Like:

```
$email_subject =  $cnm ." |abc.com";
        $email_message ="<HTML><head><tite>you're title</tile></head><BODY><TABLE>";
        $email_message .= "<TR><TD> Job Descrption :".$jb_des ."</TD></TR>\r\n\n";
        $email_message .="<TR><TD>Employer Name :".$frm_nm." </TD></TR>" ."\r\n\n";
        $email_message .="<TR><TD>Company Name :".$cnm." </TD></TR>" ."\r\n\n";
        $email_message .="<TR><TD>Message :".$msg." </TD></TR>" ."\r\n\n";
        $email_message .="<TR><TD>Title of Job Opening :".$job_ti." </TD></TR>" ."\r\n\n";
        $email_message .="</TABLE></BODY></HTML>";
        $headers = "From:<$frm_nm@".DOMAIN_WEBMAIL.">"."\r\n\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";  
        @mail($to_em,$email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Or take this header

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Another thing. It might be you're mail function. Original the function accept this parameters

```
mail(to, subject, message, headers);
```

Looking at you're mail function looks like it has one parameter too much.

For more information you can look at: [PHP mail introduction](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)
and take a look at example 4.

Hope this helps for you

Comment: i have tried ur code ,MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 is printed as it is in Email

Comment: try to remove $to_em from you're mail function

Comment: $to_em contains recipient email

Comment: Now it is working fine. it was mistaken that have written \r\n\n in header

Answer (score 2):

Use the headers below.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Header is printed as it is in email